# I have a ASP.Net Core Razor Pages Web Application That Checks User Login With Web API Call. How do i Authenticate the Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, razor-pages

I have created and hosted a Web API that checks user login and returns user information if there's a login match.
Now I have a Web Application that calls the API on every login to check if the user exists.
How do I authenticate the Web application when there's a login match in the Web API?
Article or Video will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can use forms authentication and set authentication cookie when API returns the success response. You can Google for article and videos

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya a little more help sir. I dont know what the form authentication does. I have always thought its for Web Forms.

Comment: you should use token based for this coode. and For token JWT or Bearer token is available.